# Ethereum miner does not produce blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, golang

first time Mining! Watching a YouTube Tutorial about Blockchain basics and it shows how to set up a Genesis Block as well as how to start Mining.

I've followed all the steps to the best of my abilities and got stuck up until the point where we actually Mine the block.

The YouTube instructor says it takes a bit to start mining, ~10 min according to him.

But after 10 minutes nothing was happening. After using the "Miner.stop()", it returned null. Upon further investigation, the boolean function eth.mining returned true after miner.start() and false after miner.stop(). eth.hashrate was also returning numbers ranging from 322700 to 322943. Also, under System Monitor, the CPU was all running at 100%. Being my first time mining and fixing this laptop, I didn't want anything to happen.

Any idea what's going on? Does Mining require Good Internet (using Satellite)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you probably were mining. You should use a mining calculator to work out the likelihood of mining anything though.

https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator

> Does Mining require Good Internet (using Satellite)

Mining is essentially a race against the other miners to find the solution to the next block.

Anything that slows you down in this race puts you at a disadvantage.

Does mining require a good internet connection? No. Does it make more sense to have a good internet connection? Definitely.